# Advice on solving UD in low level management functions

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, undefined-behavior, chars

I'm fairly new to C and have started out writing a small library with functionality to get length of strings, reversing strings, converting binary data in char buffers to ints and shorts. Just for the sake of education and getting a better grasps of the low level functionality that are already available in string.h etc.

The problem is that the errors I'm having are random to some degree. I have 4 functions:

- **`getStringLength`** (Gets the length of a string)
- **`reverseString`** (Reverses a string using XOR replacement and using the getStringLength to get the length)
- **`charsToUShort`** (Converts a char array pointer with two bytes (not counting null term) of binary data into a unsigned short)
- **`charsToUInt`** (Converts a char array pointer with four bytes (not counting null term) of binary data into a unsigned int)

Basically a problem occurs when I test all these functions in my main function. When all functions are used the iterator in **`reverseString`** which will go from `0` to `length / 2` is set as `32767`. So basically when the reversal of the string is getting iterated the loop doesn't even start since the iterator is `32767`. Despite that it is initialized as 0. If I only use 3 of these for functions, for example if I remove charsToUInt i my main function it all works as expected.

### The main question

- **What advice do you have to solve a problem like this?**
- All other advices are also very welcome!

---

### Error prone code for clarification

**`getStringLength`**:

```
unsigned int getStringLength(char *str){
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while(str[i]){
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

**`reverseString`**:

```
void reverseString(char *str){
    int i, m = 0;
    unsigned int l = getStringLength(str);

    m = l >> 1;

    while(i < m){
        str[i] ^= str[l - 1];
        str[l - 1] ^= str[i];
        str[i] ^= str[l - 1];
        i++;
        l--;
    }
}
```

**`charsToUShort`**:

```
unsigned short charsToUShort(char *str){
    unsigned int l = getStringLength(str);
    unsigned short result = 0;

    if(l != 2){
        return 0;
    }else{
        result |= str[0] << 8;
        result |= str[1] << 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

**`charsToUInt`**:

```
unsigned int charsToUInt(char *str){
    unsigned int l = getStringLength(str);
    unsigned int result = 0;

    if(l != 4){
        return 0;
    }else{
        result |= str[0] << 24;
        result |= str[1] << 16;
        result |= str[2] << 8;
        result |= str[3] << 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Test output for clarification

Here's the output from the testing with error result:

```
0: reverseString failed! Expected value: 'olleH', actual value: 'Hello'
1: charsToUShort passed! Expected value: '0x6261', actual value: '0x6261'
2: charsToUInt passed! Expected value: '0x62616364', actual value: '0x62616364'
```

And here's the expected result:

```
0: reverseString passed! Expected value: 'olleH', actual value: 'olleH'
1: charsToUShort passed! Expected value: '0x6261', actual value: '0x6261'
2: charsToUInt passed! Expected value: '0x62616364', actual value: '0x62616364'
```

Comment: I personally would recommend using the types `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` rather than `short` and `int`, because the sizes are more obvious, and do not change over architectures.

Comment: @shart Thanks for the advice! I'll look into the uint16_t and uint32_t and read up on changes of type size over architectures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only sets `m` to zero, `i` is left uninitialized, you want `int i = 0, m = 0;`, else the loop will never execute a single iteration

Comment: Yes, that was the exact problem. I didn't even think in that direction since the problem appeared quite randomly. Thanks for lending me your sharp eyesight! ^^

Comment: @Ancide: if you ever come across funny errors like this, its always a good idea to pump up the warning verbosity of the compiler, it'll warn you of things like this :)

Comment: I will certainly do that next time! Thanks again